# How could I copy or Insert datatable into SQLiteDataBase?

Tags: c#, sqlite

I am using web service to catch the data from SQL Server 2012 and putting it into DataTable.I want to copy or insert this datatable into SQLite database.I am making code in C#.Is there way to do so.

Comment: i think you must do manually everything(From create table to insert values)

Comment: But how can i use Insert query for datatable?

Comment: The simplest way, if you have access to the web service database you should export the database schema and data as .sql script file and run the exported script on your local SQLite database to import.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the DataTable from the source database, set the AcceptChangesDuringFill property of the data adapter to false, so that loaded records are kept in the Added state (assuming that the source db is SQL Server)

```
var sqlAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM the_table", sqlConnection);
DataTable table = new DataTable();
sqlAdapter.AcceptChangesDuringFill = false;
sqlAdapter.Fill(table);
```

Create the table in the SQLite database, by executing the CREATE TABLE statement directly with `SQLiteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery`

Create a new `DataAdapter` for the SQLite database connection, and use it to Update the db:

Answer (score 0):

for each row in data table you must do something like:

```
SQLiteConnection connSqlite = new SQLiteConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0};Version=3;", filepath));

            connSqlite.Open();
                DataTable a = new DataTable();
                for (int i = 0; i < a.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    string rowquery = "insert into tbl values(";
                    for (int z = 0; z < a.Rows[i].ItemArray.Count(); z++)
                    {
                        rowquery+=a.Rows[0].ItemArray[1].ToString();
                        if (z < a.Rows[i].ItemArray.Count() - 1)
                            rowquery += ",";
                    }
                    rowquery += ")";
                }
                SQLiteCommand commSqlite = new SQLiteCommand(strCommand, connSqlite);
                commSqlite.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this option, since it is vulnerable to SQLInjection.

Comment: this is a waypoint, you can edit it as you wish(you can edit to avoid SQLInjection)